# JPA query with condition for OneToMany hibernate relationship

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I have a `spring boot` application, where I use `JPA` to access the data in a database. Now I'd need to perform a more complex query, but I can't figure out, how to make it.

In my Repository interface, I have a working query, that selects all chatThreads of a user, by his username:

```
@Query("SELECT chatThread FROM ChatThread chatThread WHERE (chatThread.userId) = (:id)")
    public List<ChatThread> find(@Param("id") String id);
```

But how to adjust it now, to select only messages, which were not read yet?
There exists a `hibernate OneToMany relationship` and the scheme looks like that:
[image]

Comment: write a second query with this addtional condition.

Comment: ..I don't understand what do you mean? Wouldn't you mind to explain it more and post as an answer?

Comment: Do you mean to select _messages_ now or still chatThreads, only filtered now to those that have unread messages?

Comment: @HeinBlöd I want to select all chatThreads with the same userId as was passed with the parameter, plus I want those chatThreads to contain only unread Messages ~~~> Message.read == false

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your comment and assuming you have the OneToMany relationship on `ChatThread` as `List<Message> messages`, your JPQL query should look like this:

```
SELECT chatThread FROM ChatThread chatThread WHERE (chatThread.userId) = (:id) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT message FROM chatThread.messages message WHERE message.read = TRUE)
```

You might have to change the condition for message.read if you don't use boolean to integer conversion, e.g. `message.read = 1`.

Comment: This could do the job!